# Obtain the KMS Host key

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, kms

I have a machine with **Windows Server 2012** with a key of KMS Host, I lost the paper where I have the key annotated. Now I am trying to migrate the KMS host to a server with **Windows Server 2012 R2**. But I cannot obtain the key of the KMS Host from the older computer. I tried to backup from the older and put it in the newest but it did not work.

Are there any way to restore or obtain the key from the older machine to put it in the new? Or the only way is to contact with **Microsoft**?

**EDIT:** I tried to use VAMT, but the keys, it shows me, are for the clients not for the KMS Host. With those keys I cannot register the KMS Host key for the new computer. It only stores them in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your key for 2012 will not work on 2012 R2. Log into your volume license portal and get a key for 2012 R2.